# How do I prevent elements in my nav-bar being cut off when re-sizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I managed to fix a problem I was having where my nav elements where bunching up when the window is resized by adding:

```
nav ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

But now, when I resize my window, elements in my nav bar are disappearing.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One);
 body {
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#main {
  font-size: 80px;
}
nav ul li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 65px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
  display: table-cell;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  color: #999;
}
#ghostButton {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 0.5px solid white;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Times new roman";
}
#ghostButton:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#hero {
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah72/michaelbarley1/1235217_483642721808631_6410301847003523270_n_zpse3g2acn1.jpg);
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-family: "Times new roman";
}
.header1 {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-family: "Times new roman";
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=stylesheet.css.map */
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1>Elianos Brasserie</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Page1</li>
        <li>Page2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="hero">
      <div class="header">
        <h1 id="main">Made with love</h1>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
          <br>tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
          <br>aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
          <br>
        </p>
        <div id="ghostButton">Learn More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like the elements to remain spaced out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily achieve such an effect using [flexbox display properties](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I edited your code with an example of this. Using `flex-grow:1;` on the `li` they will divide the available horizontal space amongst each other. To avoid the line from wrapping you could consider adding `flex-wrap:nowrap;` to the `ul`.

Before using flexbox, consider [the browser support of flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One);
 body {
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  float:left;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 50px;
  display:flex;
}
#main {
  font-size: 80px;
}
nav ul li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  //padding: 20px 65px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
  flex-grow:1;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  color: #999;
}
#ghostButton {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 0.5px solid white;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Times new roman";
}
#ghostButton:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#hero {
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah72/michaelbarley1/1235217_483642721808631_6410301847003523270_n_zpse3g2acn1.jpg);
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-family: "Times new roman";
}
.header1 {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-family: "Times new roman";
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=stylesheet.css.map */
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1>Elianos Brasserie</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Page1</li>
        <li>Page2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="hero">
      <div class="header">
        <h1 id="main">Made with love</h1>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
          <br>tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
          <br>aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
          <br>
        </p>
        <div id="ghostButton">Learn More</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect , but, is there anyway to get the elements on the same line as the title "Elianos" ?

Comment: I just added a float:left; to the h1 to achieve this, but you could also consider putting the h1 in an li tag in your ul list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read and learn something about responsive web design. Or just add `float: left;` to your `nav ul li` .

Read more on Responsive web design [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)